# Change SQL Server edition on Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine

I have an azure vm that was created from a gallery image which included SQL Server standard edition.  I'm paying by the minute for the vm and SQL Server.  Now I need to upgrade to SQL Server enterprise edition.  Is it possible to do this without recreating the entire vm from scratch?

Comment: I'd just create a new VM.  Turn off the standard one when you're not using it and vice versa.  Should be easy enough to port the schema over.

Comment: SO is for programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have deployed a SQL Server VM the licensing for the SQL Server is included in the price of the VM. So in order to upgrade the VM azure would need to change the SKU that you are charged for but also upgrade the software inside your running VM which would be very prone to breaking something (generally a bad thing on live, potentially production machines)

So unfortunately the only way to upgrade is by launching a new VM. But if your datafiles are on separate disks you could remount those on the new machine, point the new SQL Server at them and you should be back in business pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

At this time you're not allowed to change a license for SQL Server gallery images.
You'll have to create a new VM from gallery and move the databases.